# Some questions can't possibly have an answer

Tags: logic

Suppose you're God (just for the sake of the argument,you can in fact throw God out of the argument at any time ... ) and  so you can see the universe from a special frame of reference *X* which contains  the truth about everything in the universe (its origin ,why it is so etc... ), how can you answer then this question ?

Where does *X* take its explanation ?

In other words can a God answer the question why *X* is true ? 
Surely he must have the answer if he's God but that would imply an answer which is to find outside *X* ,so *X* must have an answer in another frame *Y* through which consider *X* ,but what proves *Y*  then ?

You see that I could keep along for ever so I am led to the conclusion that there isn't a frame in which there are all the answer about the universe and there's no way we can attempt to explain everything about the universe .

In fact if I go even deeper I can state that there are some questions which can't possibly have an answer .

Comment: Why do you believe that *Y* is outside of *X*?

Comment: Because *X* can't have itself as element of the frame otherwise it would be just another element as the rest of the others and not the frame that contains it all.

Comment: most of the questions  can't possibly have an answer

Comment: This is reminiscent of [Cantor's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_paradox) as well as [Tarski's definition of truth](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tarski-truth/) in relation to the object language vs meta language. Yes, you cannot define truth in the object language you need a metal language, how do you define truth in the meta language? You need a meta meta language, and so on.

Comment: We have formal proofs that some questions are not answerable/have no answer, see [independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(mathematical_logic)) and [undecidability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem). However, this question is not an actual question it is more along the lines of "am I correct?" which is explicitly off topic on this SE.

Comment: why would you need answers that can only have meaning outside the frame of reality?

Comment: 42.. there's the answer. Yes, I'm quite certain.

Comment: Maybe there need not be a *Y*. It's possible that you're appealing to an intuition of causality, that something must have a cause or explanation, when in fact, causality need only be a trait existing within a universe, but not necessary to explain the universe as a whole. It's possible that something could just *be*. There's no reason to think that the same mechanism we use to explain things happening within the universe can coherently be applied to the universe itself.

Comment: That some questions can not have an answer is trivially true, for instance "what is the color of π?" or "is this sentence false?" Such questions often contain [category errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake), they attempt to apply predicates to objects to which they do not apply. Your " frame of reference (?) X, which contains truth about everything" already does that, but "why is X true?" is even more overtly so, "true" does not apply to "frames of reference". And surely not even God can have answers to meaningless questions.

Comment: Why do you think "true" does not apply as a predicate to X ?Suppose X has a predicate about the world ,what logical context makes the predicate 
 of X true ?

Comment: You can't prove logic is true using logic. But it makes sense to consider why logic is true at all . If the question "what makes logic true " doesn't have sense ,then what predicate do I need to apply so that it makes sense ? I am trying to understand,not to be cocky.

Comment: "What makes logic true?" is better than "why is X true?", at least we can make sense of X now. It is still problematic though, there are ways to explain what makes particular choices of logics reasonable for particular purposes, but "true" presupposes logic, and more, already in place. And the analogy does not work here, you could ask what makes the universe serve God's purposes or how God knows things about it (because he created it, presumably), but I do not see any meaningful question to which we can tell that he can not have an answer.

Comment: Number Theory might be your best area of research. They have been concerned with why integers exist for a long time. And i think it is time itself that allows logic, and arithmetic etc.

Comment: God does not think. If He is God, what is there for Him to think about - is He not all-knowing? Everything that is known or thought about the universe is from the perspective of those within the universe. All thoughts and knowledge - and questions - are within the universe. God is beyond the universe. It is a super-sensual realm. There is no 'why' or 'how' there.

Comment: I had a thought last night based on conflating numerpus posts on this forum. We can show that infinity exists, and evidence suggests the universe is only some 15bn years old. Surely this proves that our 4 dimensions are not all that exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll consider three interpretations of your question.  I’m pretty sure you are thinking of the third, but the other two are useful for building up to give the final answer.

1. "God's view" is not part of a formal system.

If the question is about non-formalized natural language, then there is no problem with allowing X (God’s frame of reference) to contain X. For example, we can talk about “everything”, which includes the concept of “everything”, without problems. We only have paradoxes resulting when we treat language and the objects language refers to formally.

2. "God's view" is an object language in a hierarchy

Since your question refers to a frame of reference Y which is necessarily outside the frame of reference X, I assume that you are asking about formal systems.  You are correct that this is exactly how formal systems are typically set up in order to avoid problems such as Russell’s paradox. As Not_Here points out in the comments, Y is the “meta-language” of the formal system, while X is the “object language”. Y can also be treated as an object language by a higher level meta-language Z, and this hierarchy goes up forever. In this framework, your “unanswerable question”, which I take to be “Where is the truth of X derived from?”, is not only unanswerable but also unaskable. That is, the question is not well-formed within the object language for X. Viewed in this way, your unanswerable question is similar to the liar’s paradox, which analyzes the sentence “This sentence is false.” If that sentence is true, then it must be false (because it says so), and if it is false, then it must be true (because it is false that it is false), so we have a contradiction.  The solution is that the truth of any sentence in the object language X can only be asserted or denied in the meta-language Y.

3. "God's view" is the entire hierarchy of all meta-languages

Since you set up your question with X being God’s view, you probably have the idea that there is no meta-language Y above X, but rather that X actually contains the entire hierarchy of languages all the way up. This is also legitimate in standard treatments of formal languages.  Frames of references are usually formalized as sets in set theory.  There is no set of all sets, but we can still talk about the class of all sets without any problems.  The only issue is that the class of all sets is not a set and therefore is not part of any of the object languages in the hierarchy.  So again questions about X (the class of all sets) can not be written in the language, so they are actually unaskable in addition to being unanswerable.

---

All of this is a description of what is typically done in formal systems.  These systems are known to be consistent and to capture all of mathematics. Your observation of unanswerable questions is a good criticism of naive semantics for language, and observations like it are part of the reason that these hierarchical formal systems were developed instead.

Comment: Thanks for your instructive answer,may I ask you where can I deepen my studies in this regard ?

Comment: The SEP article on self-reference touches on the approach I described, which is called the "cumulative hierarchy". Specifically section 3. The version that I usually think of is ZF, referred to in that article in section 3.2.  Unfortunately I don't know of any more introductory material. Usually you would have a course on the formal semantics of first order logic prior to studying the cumulative hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Some questions indeed can´t have an answer. I recommend you to investigate about Gödel's incompleteness theorems.

Basically, the first one tells you that all logic systems are either incomplete or incoherent. 
And the second implies that the only way to prove a system is coherent is if it is incoherent.

So even the "absolute truth " of god would be at the very least incomplete.

Comment: Can you expand on this with some references? It may be an accurate description (I am not familiar with it), but it is overly simplified and does not give much to understand the foundation of the position.

Comment: [scientific american article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-is-godels-theorem/),[numberphile series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4ndIDcDSGc),[Standford_encyclopedia of philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/)

Answer (score 0):

Some questions definitely can't have an answer, but this is not one of them.  There is a traditional answer that is quite logical: Berkeley-ism. 
 Traditionally, God is a rationale in-and-of-himself.

If all things are the way they are just because God wants them to be that way, then asked this question, God can always answer, and be right.  No need for regressive shell games.  Whims, in particular, need have no traceable cause, or they wouldn't be whims.

More generally, a reference is not a containment.  I can point at something, like 'The Will of God', and still have it be in the list of 'Causes of Things', even if it is the cause of the list itself, and of each of the things on it.

Whatever notion of 'frame of reference' you have seems to omit the idea that references are often circular.  You can wish Russel's paradox away by imagining otherwise, but circular references are a real thing.